# NHibernate - Store/Export Stored Procedure Definition

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, orm

I know that it is possible to execute stored procedures via NHibernate and map the return values to data objects. However, I use NHibernate's schema export capabilities to generate/update my database schema and was wondering if there is any way to store my procedure text in NHibernate and, when exporting the database schema, the stored procedure definition will also be exported. This would be extremely useful in allowing my devs to get up and running quickly with a local sandbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Auxiliary Database Objects](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-database-object)

```
<database-object>
  <create>CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc blah blah...</create>
  <drop>DROP PROCEDURE MyProc</drop>
</database-object>
```